# implement a operator - function in vector c++

Tags: c++

Hi I am trying to implement a operator - function for my vector class.

The function should takes two pre-sorted Vectors called v1 and v2 which are provided as parameters to the operator. The operator function returns a Vector that has all the elements of v2 that are common in v1 removed from v1.

For example v3 = v1 - v2;
where v1 = {2, 8, 12, 17, 22} and v2 = {17, 18, 22, 30}.

Hence the v3 should be {2, 8, 12}.

I have tried this code and its not displaying what I want, when I tried to display what is in v3 it is displaying {2,8,12,17,22}.
Could anyone help? or explain what algorithm I need implement for this to work.

```
template<class T>
MyVector<T> operator-(MyVector<T>& v1,MyVector<T>& v2)
{
    MyVector<T> v3;
    T temp;
    for(int i=0;i<v1.getCount();i++)
    {
        temp = v1.at(i);
        if(!v2.Find(temp))
        {
            v3.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    return v3;
}
```

My vector functions that are used

```
template <class T>
 bool MyVector<T>::Find(T& element)
 {
     while(start != end)
     {
         if(*start==element)
         {
             return true;
         }
         start++;
     }
     return false;
 }

 template <class T>
 void MyVector<T>::push_back(const T& element)
 {
    if(count == (capacity - 1))
    {
        MyVector::resize(capacity * 2); //double the size of vector
    }
    *end = element; //add the element to the back of the vector
    end++;  //move the vector end pointer by 1
    count++; //+1 to the current size of the vector
 }
```

Comment: If you call `Find` twice, what's the value of `start` when you enter it the second time? (Your parameters should be `const`,and `Find` should be, too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the O(n x m) solution you provided above you could do it with in a O(n + m), something like this:

```
int i=0, j=0;    

while(i < v1.getCount() && j < v2.getCount()) {
    if(v1.at(i) == v2.at(j)) {
        i++;
        j++;
    } else if(v1.at(i) < v2.at(j)) {
        v3.push_back(v1.at(i));
        i++;
    } else {
        j++;
    }
}    
    
while(i < v1.getCount()) {  // push back any remaining elements
    v3.push_back(v1.at(i));
    i++;
}
```

---

**Note:** From the question it is not clear if the values of each vector are unique and how you'd want to handle duplicate values.

For example, lets say

`v1={1, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8}`

`v2={2, 4, 7, 7, 9}`

The above solution would produce

`v3={1, 3, 7, 7, 8, 8}`.

---

If that is not what you wanted, then you might want to add some of the following:

- Add while loops for v1 and v2 to root out duplicates before they get processed:

  ```
  while(i < v1.getCount() && j < v2.getCount()) {
      while((i+1) < v1.getCount() && v1.at(i) == v1.at(i+1))
          i++;
      while((j+1) < v2.getCount() && v2.at(j) == v2.at(j+1))
          j++;
      // ...
   }

   while(i < v1.getCount()) {
       while((i+1) < v1.getCount() && v1.at(i) == v1.at(i+1))
          i++;
       // ...
   }
  ```

  result: `v3={1, 3, 8}`
- Check `v3` if the last element is the same as the one you are trying to `push_back()`.

  result: `v3={1, 3, 7, 8}`
- Use an `std::unordered_set<T>` to store overlapping elements found in `v1` and `v2`, and do a `find()` for each subsequent element you encounter in `v1` to check if it has been an overlapping element in the past.

  `std::unordered_set<>` on average has a O(1) time complexity when searching for an element, but this will of course use extra auxiliary space.

  result: `v3={1, 3, 8, 8}`
- Combine the previous two bullets points

  result: `v3={1, 3, 8}`

There are many ways to tackle this problem depending on what you expect as output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solves the issue of leftover elements in v1 that is greater than v2. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest using [std::set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)?

```
vector v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
vector v2 = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
vector<int> v3;

std::set_difference(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(v3));
// v3 now contains {2, 4, 6, 8}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/n4oKqq

Comment: Hi thanks i just notice that is what i needed, after implement my version of set_difference i got it to work! Thanks anyway.